# Exporting interface declarations in an Angular library

Tags: angular, interface, typescript-typings, angular-library

I have an Angular library which serves as a feature plugin for other Angular apps. It consists of a main module and a component which are part of the public interface.

Main component has an input whose interface (including depending interfaces) is also exported in the public-api.
When an application consumes the library, it imports the main module in a lazy-loaded module so that library bundle is not loaded until the application navigates to the route associated with lazy-loaded module.

On the other hand, application has a service building a configuration object to pass it to the library via the input. As the interface definition of this object is imported from the library, using the service before navigating to lazy-loaded route circumvents lazy-loading library bundle.

What should be the ideal way of exporting interfaces/typings for such cases? Adding a second entry point for them solves the problem, but I'm not sure if this is a good practice. I'd like to hear your ideas.

Comment: When you say `interfaces`, do you mean typescript interface declaration?

Comment: Exactly, i mean interface declarations!

Comment: Maybe `export type {...} from '...'` is what you are looking for? I know for sure at least babel elides such imports entirely. [Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export)

Comment: @AlexChashin exporting is not the actual issue here, but importing. When an application imports such types/interfaces exported from the same entry point with components only needed in a lazy loaded module leads application to load the library bundle before navigating to the route with the lazy loaded module.

Comment: Well if you only export types, then the application will only be able to import types and type imports can be elided by babel. I assume that you use babel and that type import elision works in your setup, otherwise of course this may not work

Comment: The interfaces are not ported to the JS budles. it's a typescipt "concept" that gets erased after compiling from TS to  JS. 
[Check here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-interface#:~:text=The%20TypeScript%20compiler%20does%20not,function%20or%20an%20arrow%20function.) for more info.

When tree shaking, if only type definitions (including interfaces) are used, then the bundle will not include any code from the library

Comment: @Amr thank you. this is a good read indeed. What about classes? i exported them in public_api.ts but to no avail. cant be seen when the lib is used in the web app.